# Convert milliseconds string to date in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

There were a lot of answered questions about converting milliseconds to date format but none of them was able to solve my problem.

I have a string (**and not a time**) coming in my javascript code. It is of the format as below

> 1380549600000+1000

When I try to parse it using the following code it gives me "invalid date" error.

My main objective is to convert this string to dd/mm/yyyy format. So was thinking of converting it into date and applying methods like "getMonth", etc

```
<script>
    var modDate = "1380549600000+1000"; //Note the value is in "" hence a string
    var d = new Date(modDate); //Invalid date error here
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
</script>
```

The following works just fine. But this is not the format I am getting.

```
<script>
    var modDate = 1380549600000+1000; //Note the value is no longer in ""
    var d = new Date(modDate); //No problems here
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
</script>
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Cheers.

Comment: What are you trying to say by `+1000`?

Comment: If you remove the totally invalid `+1000` and parse it as a number, it should work fine

Comment: Use eval() to evaluate and then use your date logic, because + will be considered as illegal character if you try to parse it.

Comment: What is that *format*? @leopik If it is a timezone, it's a +1s timezone 0_o

Comment: So you have to check if there is a non-numeric caracter in you string, if yes, remove the following caracters (numbers) after this non-numeric, get the result to be formatted in date.

Comment: Let me confirm that the "+1000" in your string is Milliseconds,  Is that correct?  If it is, you can drop it, by either splitting on the `+`, discarding it and then running it through `parseInt`, or just running through `parseInt`, which will drop it.  See my answer for more information.

Comment: You probably want this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/r8uhb7yo/1/**

Comment: @Mike I think +1000 is a timestamp and not milliseconds as it is giving me a date with 1 day less

Comment: Its all a time-stamp.  You may mean "Timezone." Yet, as it is a time-stamp, and these usually don't include the timezone, and there are 1000 milliseconds in a second, and you state that the time-stamp is in milliseconds, all indicates that the "+1000" is millis. To better help (debugging what this string is, and the way to treat it) we will need more information: Where is the string coming from, what is the timezone on that system, as well as your local timezone, and can you give us a reported time-stamp from the system generating the string, and the expected time at the time of generation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit:-

eval is not the best approach, it is not safe to use eval, so use this instead:-

```
var modDate = "1380549600000+1000"
var temp = modDate.split("+");
modDate = parseInt(temp[0]) + parseInt(temp[1]);
```

I am not sure if you need that added 1000, if you don't, it could be done in one line as :-

```
modDate = parseInt(modDate.split("+")[0])
```

older approach :-

```
<script>
var modDate = eval("1380549600000+1000"); //Note the value is in "" hence a string
var d = new Date(modDate); //Invalid date error here
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
</script>
```

Comment: That evals the string as javascript and returns the result, which is, quite literally, the math.

Comment: safer to split on + then add normally

Comment: @Mike which is quite exactly the problem that the OP is facing right?

Comment: @NamitSingal no. The +1000 is the timezone. The date expected is not intended to be the result of the addition operation. That means it's the timestamp given plus 10 hours.

Comment: True, it's an assumption, but given the format a highly likely one. I would imagine the OP has not spotted the difference between the timezone addition yet.

Comment: @AlexK. safer to use split, let me add

Comment: But still, eval'ing strings coming "from somewhere" seems like a horrible idea.

Comment: `parseInt` would avoid general risk of `eval`

Comment: I didn't add it as a comment on the question as you pointed out the fallacy of a 1s timezone yourself. Anyway - we digress. Best to leave this one as it is :)

Comment: ```eval``` is a poor practice in JS

Comment: You still insist on adding the "1000", which is miliseconds, to the seconds, why?

Comment: @Mike I was not clear about it being in milliseconds, I will remove it. thanks

Comment: "Convert milliseconds string to date in javascript", that is the format of a miliseconds string.

Comment: Thanks all for your inputs. When I use eval or split method, it is giving me a date which is 1 day less than the actual date. Probably +1000 means the timestamp i.e. UTC + 10 hours just as @RoryMcCrossan mentioned as I am operating from Australia. Any help on this front?

Comment: @samar If you use the milliseconds `Date` constructor, it adds X ms onto the time since 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC. if you want it in your desired timezone, you'd need to add the necessary number of hours. If `+1000` represents `+10` *hours*, that is quite confusing

Comment: you could either take a constant value as number of milliseconds, keep it in a variable, and add it to the modDate seconds, if this is consistent across inputs.

Comment: @NamitSingal; I multiplied "60 * 60 * 10" to the 1000 and it gave me the correct date! I am a little weak in this kind of date format so cannot comment much. Anyways will test and check. Thanks a lot. Marking your post as answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseInt` to get the numeric value of the string (safer than `eval`, but same premise):

```
modDate = (isNaN(modDate)) ? parseInt(modDate, 10) : modDate;

if !isNaN(modDate) {
    var d = new Date(modDate);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
} else {
    console.log("Value in modDate not a number");
}
```

Comment: This ignores potentially pertinent information after the `+`

Comment: Sounds to me like we're trying to safely and reasonably account for any possible value of the string, which is unrealistic. What pertinent information would follow the `+` that wouldn't require changing the parameters of the original question?

Comment: The question is outstandingly unclear, I'll admit. Just highlighting the fact that this would produce a different output to the OP's "working" example.

Comment: And you're missing a radix

Comment: an optional radix. buh.

Comment: optional in a way that causes certain issues with octals

Comment: Updated to account for initial value being integer or string, and logging error if `parseInt` returns `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks all for your inputs. When I use the parseInt method, it is giving me a date which is 1 day less than the actual date. Probably +1000 means the timestamp i.e. UTC + 10 hours as I am operating from Australia. Any help on this front?

Answer (score 1):

Other approach w/o using eval:

```
var modDate = "1380549600000+1000";
var d = new Date(modDate.split("+")
    .map(parseFloat)
    .reduce(function(a,b){return a + b;}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a bit of a mishmash of the answers here to get mine to work.
My Date value was being sent to my web page as a String, like so: "/Date(978278400000-0500)/"

So I parsed it like this, to get it to display as a valid date:

```
// sDateString = "/Date(978278400000-0500)/";
 var modDate = sDateString.replace(/[\/Date\(\)]/g, "");
 return new Date(parseInt(modDate, 10));
//returns: Sun Dec 31 2000 11:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) {}
```